# ODATA to Oracle SQL conversion using Java

Tags: odata

I am getting ODATA string from the Web Client (written using HTML5+ Angular) in my Java spring rest controller. Now My database is Oracle. Is there any tool available to convert this ODATA query string to Oracle SQL query in Java ?

Otherwise I will have to manually write parser to achieve this. Please suggest.